# Nextjs - Nested Dynamic routes - pages/users/[uid]/goals/[goalId]

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js

I'd like to have the following page structure: /users/[userId]/goals/[goaldId]. For example: website.com/users/1234/goals/0912834

What folder structure do I need for that? I'm current trying this:

pages/

- users/

  - [uid].tsx
  - goals/

    - [goalId].tsx

I've tried searching but haven't founded anything similar yet. Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you getting any errors while doing that folder structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should work. [uid] should be a directory and not a tsx file.

```
pages/
    users/
        [uid]/
            goals/
                [goalId].tsx
```

you can checkout this example here https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/dynamic-routing/pages/post

Comment: That worked great! I have [uid] as a folder and page so that I can have /users/1234 as a page and /users/1234/goals/10981 as a page too. Thank you!